# Can't access Docker container on exposed port from anywhere even localhost

Tags: ubuntu, docker, fedora, minecraft, iptables

I have been searching for an answer for this for days and don't know the best place to ask for help, I must be missing something simple.

This problem is common to both my Fedora27 workstation and Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

I have installed Docker successfully and have some containers working but others cannot be accessed on 0.0.0.0: or localIP:

I have disabled firewall and flushed iptables, amongst others I am trying to get a minecraft server running on 25565, following this instruction:

> To simply use the latest stable version, run
>
> `docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc itzg/minecraft-server`
>
> where the standard server
> port, 25565, will be exposed on your host machine.

The container runs OK:

```
[benjbt@localhost ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND       CREATED        STATUS                  PORTS                                NAMES
3240121d414e  itzg/minecraft-server:latest    "/start"      2 minutes ago  Up 2 minutes (healthy)  0.0.0.0:25565->25565/tcp, 25575/tcp  mc
8f1cf88207e7  portainer/portainer             "/portainer"  9 minutes ago  Up 9 minutes            0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp               eager_northcutt
```

However, the port is not accessible:

```
can’t establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:25565
```

Please help me understand what is blocking my port?

```
[benjbt@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp 
dpt:cslistener
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp 
dpt:25565

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

TROUBLESHOOTING: Answers from @BMitch comment

1. The Container seems healthy

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
    6b5822a781c1        rlenferink/minecraft:latest   "/start"            38 hours ago        Up 38 hours         0.0.0.0:25565->25565/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25565->25565/udp   mc
    8f592bb99d8e        portainer/portainer           "/portainer"        8 days ago          Up 45 hours         0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                               practical_goldwasser

    root@server:~# docker logs mc
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.12.2
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
    [08:55:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
    [08:55:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 488 advancements
    [08:55:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
    [08:55:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 2%
    [08:55:22] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 18%
    [08:55:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 74%
    [08:55:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (3.947s)! For help, type "help" or     "?"
        root@server:~# docker container inspect mc
    [
        {
            "Id": "6b5822a781c147012e1aa279320ce1cb235193a11da2e8a640848ce252c56027",
            "Created": "2018-05-13T08:55:08.363756829Z",
            "Path": "/start",
            "Args": [],
            "State": {
                "Status": "running",
                "Running": true,
                "Paused": false,
                "Restarting": false,
                "OOMKilled": false,
                "Dead": false,
                "Pid": 15719,
                "ExitCode": 0,
                "Error": "",
                "StartedAt": "2018-05-13T08:55:10.734864313Z",
                "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "Image": "sha256:648452c4d7be732fc87d5bcb393e94cacd8a22fc7fbb3f98bfb655aaa9f0d400",
            "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6b5822a781c147012e1aa279320ce1cb235193a11da2e8a640848ce252c56027/resolv.conf",
            "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6b5822a781c147012e1aa279320ce1cb235193a11da2e8a640848ce252c56027/hostname",
            "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6b5822a781c147012e1aa279320ce1cb235193a11da2e8a640848ce252c56027/hosts",
            "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6b5822a781c147012e1aa279320ce1cb235193a11da2e8a640848ce252c56027/6b5822a781c147012e1aa279320ce1cb235193a11da2e8a640848ce252c56027-json.log",
            "Name": "/mc",
            "RestartCount": 0,
            "Driver": "overlay2",
            "Platform": "linux",
            "MountLabel": "",
            "ProcessLabel": "",
            "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
            "ExecIDs": null,
            "HostConfig": {
                "Binds": [
                    "/mnt/minecraft:/data"
                ],
                "ContainerIDFile": "",
                "LogConfig": {
                    "Type": "json-file",
                    "Config": {}
                },
                "NetworkMode": "bridge",
                "PortBindings": {
                    "25565/tcp": [
                        {
                            "HostIp": "",
                            "HostPort": "25565"
                        }
                    ],
                    "25565/udp": [
                        {
                            "HostIp": "",
                            "HostPort": "25565"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Name": "no",
                    "MaximumRetryCount": 0
                },
                "AutoRemove": false,
                "VolumeDriver": "",
                "VolumesFrom": null,
                "CapAdd": null,
                "CapDrop": null,
                "Dns": [],
                "DnsOptions": [],
                "DnsSearch": [],
                "ExtraHosts": null,
                "GroupAdd": null,
                "IpcMode": "shareable",
                "Cgroup": "",
                "Links": null,
                "OomScoreAdj": 0,
                "PidMode": "",
                "Privileged": false,
                "PublishAllPorts": false,
                "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
                "SecurityOpt": null,
                "UTSMode": "",
                "UsernsMode": "",
                "ShmSize": 67108864,
                "Runtime": "runc",
                "ConsoleSize": [
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "Isolation": "",
                "CpuShares": 0,
                "Memory": 0,
                "NanoCpus": 0,
                "CgroupParent": "",
                "BlkioWeight": 0,
                "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
                "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
                "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
                "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
                "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
                "CpuPeriod": 0,
                "CpuQuota": 0,
                "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
                "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
                "CpusetCpus": "",
                "CpusetMems": "",
                "Devices": [],
                "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
                "DiskQuota": 0,
                "KernelMemory": 0,
                "MemoryReservation": 0,
                "MemorySwap": 0,
                "MemorySwappiness": null,
                "OomKillDisable": false,
                "PidsLimit": 0,
                "Ulimits": null,
                "CpuCount": 0,
                "CpuPercent": 0,
                "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
                "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
            },
            "GraphDriver": {
                "Data": {
                    "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f5f630442b65a59c7f174a8aad1dc356cb6f565e76b2ca4afa49132afbaf30d-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a93b9c08d02aa86d8a53f5a32f166c8b40932f1430d4f9e3fd4e9c9e96af6557/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/21b66b86842fd4c456df6ea2493edbabcd0df49f468100c9c2d7d2ef55711501/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e10484efe17398912f63644cff926875cd10fa8169d1ef2f1164d1000ccd7b06/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9b110a14a5fd9640fd95161c1fa35ec8cb98b4fb55a7caf70231b1b8ba238559/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a1cb33255806e73a1d7f9efd49c2bfcbb6edf190ed1976889cb10d3f81682c9f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67286cfad81daababf3bac63ff9684c9567cd877e1e2ce4888d59257da4a06ca/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6904d0950327c52355e8b34b16d822b4eddf817de272f965f6fc6ad31089227d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6b782d3f37da3bf2c36ed70f6302d282ca4c80d39b3de3933b14902d149cfec/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e4eac39fc7fade8117216f45e9fe85bb42537714c19c02c70aab4ed62fad474e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/227df1848d1a3038188689c1f343ad42758bc6be9872ca8dda843a13b0bbf93e/diff",
                    "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f5f630442b65a59c7f174a8aad1dc356cb6f565e76b2ca4afa49132afbaf30d/merged",
                    "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f5f630442b65a59c7f174a8aad1dc356cb6f565e76b2ca4afa49132afbaf30d/diff",
                    "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f5f630442b65a59c7f174a8aad1dc356cb6f565e76b2ca4afa49132afbaf30d/work"
                },
                "Name": "overlay2"
            },
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "bind",
                    "Source": "/mnt/minecraft",
                    "Destination": "/data",
                    "Mode": "",
                    "RW": true,
                    "Propagation": "rprivate"
                }
            ],
            "Config": {
                "Hostname": "34cb1418fb23",
                "Domainname": "",
                "User": "",
                "AttachStdin": false,
                "AttachStdout": false,
                "AttachStderr": false,
                "ExposedPorts": {
                    "25565/tcp": {},
                    "25565/udp": {}
                },
                "Tty": false,
                "OpenStdin": false,
                "StdinOnce": false,
                "Env": [
                    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                    "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive"
                ],
                "Cmd": [
                    "/start"
                ],
                "Image": "rlenferink/minecraft:latest",
                "Volumes": {
                    "/data": {}
                },
                "WorkingDir": "",
                "Entrypoint": null,
                "OnBuild": null,
                "Labels": {}
            },
            "NetworkSettings": {
                "Bridge": "",
                "SandboxID": "e2c693daed0be5a204a83d408262a0fe01b66bdd99ddbb3a53229f5a58d5202c",
                "HairpinMode": false,
                "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
                "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "Ports": {
                    "25565/tcp": [
                        {
                            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                            "HostPort": "25565"
                        }
                    ],
                    "25565/udp": [
                        {
                            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                            "HostPort": "25565"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e2c693daed0b",
                "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
                "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
                "EndpointID": "819a8255b8ed4d79366a6d6ff4442a441f61d89bdfacc0c193ed2f9340024696",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "Networks": {
                    "bridge": {
                        "IPAMConfig": {},
                        "Links": null,
                        "Aliases": null,
                        "NetworkID": "e2ff1284a59794e19dd4dc39b17713ad11e0db3e698735014579405355f516ec",
                        "EndpointID": "819a8255b8ed4d79366a6d6ff4442a441f61d89bdfacc0c193ed2f9340024696",
                        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                        "IPv6Gateway": "",
                        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                        "DriverOpts": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

2. Netshoot

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
    tcp        0      0 :::25565                :::*                    LISTEN
```

3. 

```
    root@server:~# echo $DOCKER_HOST
    
    root@server:~#
```

4. On local machine

```
    $ curl http://127.0.0.1:25565
    curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

5. Local machine on firefox

```
    Problem loading page on...
    0.0.0.0:25565
    127.0.0.1:25565
    localhost:25565
    192.168.15.22:25565
```

Comment: Hi benjbt, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask for a clarification - in your client, are you trying to connect to "0.0.0.0:25565" ?

Comment: Also check if the container itself is working properly. You can check it through `docker ps` command

Comment: Thanks @VinceBowdren, yes exactly I am trying to connect from the host to 0.0.0.0:25565

Comment: @MostafaHussein thanks for the comment. Yes it seems to be running fine [benjbt@localhost ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                 NAMES
3240121d414e        itzg/minecraft-server:latest   "/start"            2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:25565->25565/tcp, 25575/tcp   mc
8f1cf88207e7        portainer/portainer            "/portainer"        9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes             0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                eager_northcutt

Comment: What about connecting through 127.0.0.1:25565 ? 0.0.0.0 means that the container can receive connections from any interface and you need an ip for that either public or internal or localhost

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1:25565 ; localhost:25565 ; 192.168.15.12:25565 ; 172.17.0.3:25565 but the problem persists. I was originally trying on my server via 192.168.12.22:25565 and it didn't work so I pulled it back to my workstation to troubleshoot but it seems like the port isn't open

Comment: type `docker logs mc`

Comment: test your ports accessibility with running `docker run -d -p 25565:80 nginx` and trying to send HTTP request to that port

Comment: Logs are too long to post but something interesting is >[22:35:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565

Comment: Thanks @AndriyMaletsky that was a good idea. I can see Welcome to nginx on port 0.0.0.0:25565 so it's not the port then.

Comment: Having confirmed that I can connect to that port I have retried to get a minecraft server up but am still having the same problem. I have tried 2 different images, tried again on my server running ubuntu but still cant connect to the minecraft server on 0.0.0.0:25565 any other thoughts please?

Comment: Hi benjpt; just to let you know, 0.0.0.0 is an instruction to your server program to listen on all available interfaces - [it isn't an address itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0). The correct way to address this server is at 127.0.0.1:25565 (if the client is a non-docker program running on the same computer), or 192.168.12.22:25565 (or whatever your computer's IP address is) if connecting from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Vince, I also cant connect on 127.0.0.1 or localhost where everything I read says I should be able to easily. It's really puzzling.

Answer (score 4):

Several things to check:

1. Make sure your application is healthy. Check `docker logs mc` for any error messages and `docker container inspect mc` for the last exit/restart time of the container.
2. Check that the application is listening on the desired port. For this, I like netshoot:

   `docker run -it --rm --net container:mc nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt`

   This should show output with your port, listening on `0.0.0.0:25565`.
3. Check if you are running your docker commands locally or against a remote instance or VM. `echo $DOCKER_HOST` and if that has a value, connect to that IP address instead of `127.0.0.1`.
4. If you are logged into a remote machine to run docker commands (e.g. ssh), test locally on that machine first (e.g. `curl http://127.0.0.1:25565`) before trying to access it remotely where firewalls may block the connectivity.
5. Lastly, as mentioned in the comments, don't connect to `0.0.0.0` from the client. This is effectively a wildcard IP address that tells the server application to listen on all network interfaces. You don't connect to that from your client/web browser. Instead, use the actual IP or DNS name of the host.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch for the helpful troubleshooting advice. I have stepped through them all but I cannot find anything, perhaps you can, I'll add the detail to my original question.

Comment: The curl error indicates that you can connect to the container and the application itself is closing the connection. I'm not a Minecraft expert, so not sure if it talks http. Either way, not a docker connectivity error, but an app or client problem.